# How to get all labels and its input elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to get all labels and its input elements using Javascript.
I have also radio, checkboxes and textarea elements.
Then I want to put it in an array of objects.

This is what I have done,

```
var html = data;
var array = [];
for(var i=0;i<$("input").length;i++){
    array[i] = {label:"",val:$("input").eq(i).val()};
}
console.log(array);
```

By the way,  doesn't have for attributes and also their next sibling is not always the input/radio/checkbox/textarea element. Sometimes,the structures are,

```
<label>Something:</label><Br/ ><input type="text" />
```

How can I do what I want in this situation?

Comment: So the label may or may not be near or around or IN ANY WAY REFERRING to its input element? How are you supposed to know which labels go with which inputs?

Comment: `label` is not an `input` control.

Comment: No, but I get his point: @JMA wants some sort of label to each input. label is a normally a cosmetic referent to the input, so there is normally a relationship there.

Comment: You are not using `<label>`  correctly.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. If there are different structures then there won't be a *"one size fits all"* answer

Comment: Why do you not utilize `for` attribute?

Comment: Don't use a `for` loop to iterate over jQuery collections, use `$("input").each(...)`

Comment: And if you want to make an array of results, use `$("input").map(...).get()`

Comment: A `<label>` should either be wrapped around the input like `<label>Text<input></label>` or it should have a `for` attribute `<label for="inputID">Text</label><input id="inputID">`

Comment: If you don't do one of these, the browser doesn't link the label with the input.

Comment: Share all the possible html structure

Comment: Sorry, the html variable is not related to this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) method to generate the array and use [`prevAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/) method with jQuery [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) pseudo-class selector to get the label(you can't use [`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) method since there is a `br` tag in between).

```
var array = $("input").map(function(){
  return { 
    label : $(this).prevAll('label:first').text(),
    val:$(this).val()
  };
}).get();

console.log(array);
```

---

**FYI :** If the input is wrapped by `label` in some case then you can use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to get the wrapped element. Although you can use [`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) to select all form elements.

```js
var array = $(":input").map(function() {
  return {
    label: $(this).prevAll('label:first').text(),
    val: $(this).val()
  };
}).get();

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Some</label>
<Br/>
<input type="text" value="1" />
<label>Some1</label>
<Br/>
<input type="text" value="11" />
<label>Some2</label>
<Br/>
<input type="text" value="2" />
<label>Some3</label>
<Br/>
<input type="text" value="4" />
<label>Some4</label>
<Br/>
<input type="text" value="3" />

<label>Some422</label>
<Br/>
<select><option value="1"></option><select>
```

Comment: Would this work if there are multiple 'labels' on one row and the input fields on the next?  In that case, not sure you could associate the label with the input unless you tag each to tie them together.

Comment: @rasmeister only the nearest one get selected

Comment: won't work on radios or checkboxes if label is wrapping them

Comment: @charlietfl : the code would work on the shared code..... the problem may be the `br` in between (Taken from ques : _"By the way, doesn't have for attributes and also their next sibling is not always the input/radio/checkbox/textarea element."_)

Comment: OP is only showing one case , but says there are others. I am simply pointing out this probably isn't a one size fits all answer

Comment: My guess is there are probably numerous conditions to check

Comment: If I have this situation, can I use $("input, textarea,select") to select all needed elements? How can I get the value of radio buttons using this answer?

Comment: @JMA : check the snippet added

Comment: Is this the same results if I used $("input,textarea")? and also the checkboxes and radiobuttons are also included?

Comment: @JMA : `:input` for selecting all form elements

Comment: Hey, I used your solution, but the problem is, the radio button, {label:"radio",val:"USD",label:"radio",val:"PHP"} so I don't get the selected answer

Comment: @JMA : for radio you need to get element based on name

Comment: Can you show me that? I will use (typeof $(this) == "radio")?"":"". Names are the same. but still not working

Answer (score 1):

You're using labels wrong so I'm going to assume what you really want is just some identifying attribute of the text field checkbox etc to associate with the value.

Here is my go
https://jsfiddle.net/1akh5qg9/

HTML

```
<form id="test-form">
  <label>Label1:</label>
  <input class="get-value" name="input1" type="text" />
  <br>
  <label>Label2:</label>
  <input class="get-value" name="input2" type="text" />
  <br>
  <label>Label3:</label>
  <input class="get-value" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">I have a bike
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="submit-button">Get Values</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
let btn = document.getElementById('submit-button');
let form = document.forms['test-form'].getElementsByClassName('get-value');
let valueArr = [];

// attach onclick handler
btn.onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  getFormValues();
}

// getFormValues
function getFormValues() {
 for (var x of form){
  valueArr.push({label:x.name ,value:x.value})
 }
 console.log(valueArr);
}
```

Results

```
[
 {label:"input1", value:"test1"}, 
 {label:"input2", value:"test1"}, 
 {label:"checkbox1", value:"on"}
]
```

Comment: I can't use this because the user can change the class. +1. Thanks for a good answer.

Comment: What is the context that this is being used in? You can have the user add values to a class instead of changing it. So for example it could be `class="get-value user-defined user-defined-2"` then the above would still work

Comment: I am using it in a Form builder plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For you to get the label tags in your HTML form you first have to get the label tag from the DOM and follow up with the code below:

```
// get array of label tags in the DOM
const label = document.getElementsByTagName("label")
for (k = 0; k < label.length; k++){
    const labelText = Array.prototype.filter
    .call(label[k].childNodes, x => x.nodeName === "#text")
    .map(x => x.textContent)
    console.log(labelText)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to select all elements (labels, inputs) into a single array, try using a custom attribute and use a selector like this $('*[data-all-labels-inputs]');

Comment: If the OP could add attributes to the DOM elements, they probably would just use ids on the inputs and `for="..."` on the labels

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend doing something up-front in the HTML to mark the items you want to get.

You could put the label and input pairs in a DIV to indicate that they go together and then give the DIV a class that you could filter and loop on.

You could also use data-tag attributes to name the pairs. Say give all the labels and inputs the attribute  data-LabelInp="NameA".  Then you can select all labels with attribute data-LabelInp, get the value of the attribute and find the matching input with data-LabelInp === that value.