# How to get item from listview to disable href

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i get text of each row from Label1?

My .aspx

```
        <asp:ListView ID="lvRestaurant" runat="server" DataSourceID="ldsOrder" DataKeyName="restaurantID">
            <LayoutTemplate>
            <div>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="groupPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <GroupTemplate>
                <div class="restaurant">
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </div>

            </GroupTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("restaurantID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label></div> 
                <div><a href="foodDetails.aspx?restaurantID=<%#Eval("restaurantID") %>" style="text-decoration:none;" draggable="false" id="orderPage"><asp:Image ID="imgRestaurant" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image", "../resImg/{0}") %>' draggable="false" CssClass="restaurant-img"/></a></div>
               <div class="resName"><b><asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("restaurantName") %>'></asp:Label></b></div>
               <div class="deliveryFee"><b>MYR<asp:Label ID="lblDeliveryFee" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("deliverFee") %>'></asp:Label></b>&nbsp;<span style="color:#C3C3C3;">delivery fee</span></div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

I try to make if cart exist 1 restaurant product, other restaurant will not be able to click.
My .cs

```
    if(Session["BuyItems"]!=null{
           string rID = //get from Label1;
           if(rID==Session[existID].ToString()){
                orderPage.HreF="#";
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at foreach, maybe this links can help you.

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1029041/How-to-loop-through-a-listbox-items-in-asp-net

[How to get all labels and its input elements in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984980/how-to-get-all-labels-and-its-input-elements-in-javascript/41985099)

https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-get-text-from-a-label-in-a-datalist-itemtemplate/6088/18

**Pseudocode**

```
if(Session["BuyItems"]!=null
{
       string rID = 5; // for example
       foreach (var item in YourListWithRestaurants)
       {
            if(rID != Session[existID].ToString())
            {
                // Make the restaurants unable to click
            }
       }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Add an OnItemCommand with ListView:

```
OnItemCommand="ListView_ItemCommand" >
```

Then you can write an eventhandler:

```
protected void ListView_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Label label1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1");
}
```